# Laravel 4 - HTML Purifier

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-4

I am using the html purifier https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier to filter the text from an input like this:

```
  $body = Input::get('body');
  $purifiedtext = Purifier::clean($body);
```

Then the `$purifiedtext` variable is stored to the database so that it could be retrieved later in the view. This is working and filters the text but when I am retrieving it, the html markup is visible instead of producing the correct output.

This is how I am trying to retrieve the stored $purifiedtext with blade:

```
{{{ $upload->body }}}
```

For example if the input for body is 'some text' wrapped with h2 tags then the output should be:

### some text

Now is just returning the text like this: `<h2>some text</h2>`

How can I change that so it will know about the tags and format the content appropriately?

Should I use `htmlentities` to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are escaping your text in Blade:

```
{{{ $upload->body }}}
```

Removing the extra curly braces should make it work:

```
{{ $upload->body }}
```

Comment: That is genius! I started looking at things to extend blade, http://laravel.com/docs/templates#extending-blade. I couldn't even imagine that this would work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

remove the thirth bracket... don't escape html returned from mysql, that does not work

use `{{ $upload->body }}` instead

Comment: LOL somebody is faster than me :-)